# Split string into groups by inside and outside of brackets - including the brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for the simplest way to parse a string into groups - including the delimiters. What's inside and outside the `{ }` could be anything - except for `{` and `}`.

Using this

```
var s = "test {#}, {1} more text {a|b|c}";  
var regEx = new Regex(@"{(.*?)}");  
var mat = regEx.Matches(s);
```

I get groups that are `["{#}", "{1}", "{a|b|c}"]`.

My desired result is `["test ", "{#}", ", ", "{1}", " more text ", "{a|b|c}"]`.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion this is an [X/Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You seem to be going down the path of reimplementing[`string.Format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-6.0#system-string-format(system-string-system-object()))

Comment: @Thefourthbird - OP specified that there will be no nesting of any kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If inside and outside can be anything except for `{` and `}`:

```
\{[^{}]*}|[^{}]+
```

**Explanation**

- `{` Match the opening `{`
- `[^{}]*` Optionally match any char except `{` and `}`
- `}` Match the closing `}`
- `|` Or
- `[^{}]+` match 1+ chars other than `{` and `}`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l4s6Zm/1)

Example

```
string pattern = @"{[^{}]*}|[^{}]+";
string input = @"test {#}, {1} more text {a|b|c}";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", m.Value);
}
```

Output

```
'test '
'{#}'
', '
'{1}'
' more text '
'{a|b|c}'
```

Comment: @PM77-1 It does not need escaping, thanks!

Comment: ah, basically I missed the Or and the StartsWith. Line 1 of your explanation should be `^{`

Answer (score 1):

The [Regex.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=net-6.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-split(system-string)) method can find the bracketed text as separators for the split. Exclosing the separator in capture brackets means that both the separators and the other text is saved. The following code gives what is required.

```
        var s = "test {#}, {1} more text {a|b|c}";
        Regex regEx = new Regex(@"(\{.*?\})");
        string[] substrings = regEx.Split(s);

        foreach (string match in substrings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", match);
        }
```